# Why can’t I SSH to my PC from another network?

Tags: ssh

I have a desktop PC and a laptop. I'm trying to SSH into my desktop from my laptop so I can run some code way faster when I'm not home.

If both computers are on the same network, I can just do `ssh myuser@localipv4address` and that works fine

However when my laptop is connected to another network, I try to do `ssh myuser@publicipv4address` from my laptop but it just gets stuck there for a while and then throws Connection timed out

What should I do to be able to ssh in from another network?

So I ran `netstat -a` and got this line:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    192.168.0.80:22        192.168.0.193:55390    ESTABLISHED
```

That's the local IPv4 of my computer and the state shows as established instead of listening

What should I do?

Comment: What is the model of your router? You will need to set up port forwarding so when you do: `ssh myuser@publicipv4address`, your router knows to connect you to your local computer once the public IP is hit. It will map PublicIP:Port to a specific LocalIP:Port. Right now, when you hit the publicIP, the router doesnt know what device behind your router to send the ssh request to

Comment: @Narzard I have a Technicolor DPC3848VE DOCSIS 3.0 Gateway

Comment: You need to enable port forwarding on your router so you can SSH into your home network to your desktop PC and that’s really it. That said, many routers need SSH (port 22) forts own purposes. So you might have to setup a different port address — like port 222 to be what you SSH into from outside of your home. But how to do that? You need to check your router to see if it is capable of port forwarding at all.

Comment: It does have a "Port Range Forwarding" feature but I think I never got it to work

Comment: [1] What are the local & Public IP Addresses of your Desktop ? [2] Can you Ping/SSH in your local network with your Public IP ? [3] Can you Ping your Desktop with other network ? [4] What is the output of "trace route" from other network to Desktop ? [5] What firewall Configuration you have ? [6] What is the output of `nmap localIP` & `nmap PublicIP` ?

Comment: Does your router have a settings page where it shows its own WAN IP address? Is that address public, and does it match the address that you've been trying to connect to?